# PHP Object Assignment vs Cloning

Tags: php, object

I know this is covered in the php docs but I got confused with this issue .

From the php docs :

```
$instance = new SimpleClass();
$assigned   =  $instance;
$reference  =& $instance;
$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
$instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null
var_dump($instance);
var_dump($reference);
var_dump($assigned);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
NULL
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
["var"]=>
 string(30) "$assigned will have this value"
}
```

OK so I see that `$assigned` *survived* the original object (`$instance`) being assigned to `null`, so obviously `$assigned` isn't a reference but a copy of $instance.

So what is the difference between

```
 $assigned = $instance
```

and

```
 $assigned = clone $instance
```

Comment: `'$assigned will have this value'` it will not because you use `''`

Comment: @Robert In this case "$assigned" is meant to be literally "$assigned", not a value substitution.

Comment: I spent several hours today with a difficult bug that was due to my not understanding the extreme difference between assignment statements involving arrays and objects. I still don't understand WHY there is a difference. It just seems like bad language design, since objects are just fancy arrays (with visibility control, a fixed property list, and methods added). In general, when I use an assignment statement, I almost always want to capture the current value of the right-hand-side expression. In the rare cases where I want an alias (reference), I expect to need the '&' operator on the RHS.

Comment: Topical canonical: [How do I create a copy of an object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185934/2943403)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Objects are abstract data in memory. A variable always holds a *reference* to this data in memory. Imagine that `$foo = new Bar` creates an object instance of `Bar` somewhere in memory, assigns it some id `#42`, and `$foo` now holds this `#42` as reference to this object. Assigning this reference to other variables *by reference* or normally works the same as with any other values. Many variables can hold a copy of this reference, but all point to the same object.

`clone` explicitly creates a copy of the object itself, not just of the reference that points to the object.

```
$foo = new Bar;   // $foo holds a reference to an instance of Bar
$bar = $foo;      // $bar holds a copy of the reference to the instance of Bar
$baz =& $foo;     // $baz references the same reference to the instance of Bar as $foo
```

Just don't confuse "reference" as in `=&` with "reference" as in *object identifier*.

```
$blarg = clone $foo;  // the instance of Bar that $foo referenced was copied
                      // into a new instance of Bar and $blarg now holds a reference
                      // to that new instance
```

Answer (score 13):

The difference between

```
 $assigned = $instance
```

and

```
 $assigned = clone $instance
```

is that in first case you assign a reference of already existing object and in second one you create a new object and assign it to the variable.

Moreover, when you use **clone** keyword you can use magic method  __clone() which gives you better control on object cloning. From php manual:

> Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.

From [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Let me give you a live example

```
$dateA = new \Datetime('2017-04-04');

$dateB = $dateA; // $dateB references exactly the same object as $dateA

$dateB->modify('+1 day');

var_dump($dateA->format('Y-m-d')); //string(10) "2017-04-05" 
var_dump($dateB->format('Y-m-d')); //string(10) "2017-04-05"


// $dateA is still modified by the code above so it has 2017-04-05
$dateC = clone $dateA; // we clone $dateA so it's a new object

$dateC->modify('+1 day');

var_dump($dateA->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2017-04-05" 
var_dump($dateC->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2017-04-06"
```

// side note for datetime I recommend using DatetimeImmutable instead of Datetime

**EDIT: internal types**

```
// create 2 integer variables $a and $b

$a = 1;
$b = 1;

// create a new $c variable and assign the *value* of $a to that variable
$c = $a;

// create a new $d variable and assign a reference to $b variable
$d = &$b;

// increment $b, $c and $d variables
$b++; 
$c++;
$d++;

echo $a; // 1
echo $b; // 3
echo $c; // 2
echo $d; // 3
```

because $d references $b when we increment its value it'll also change the value of $b.

The difference between internal objects like strings, int, float etc. is that they are passed by value and objects are passed by default via reference

**Notice**: You cannot use clone with internal objects.

Comment: can you include &= use case in your code? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @VishwasAtrey I've included it

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't manage the objects the same way it manages the other data types. A string (or an integer, boolean, float or array) is directly stored in the variable. When the value of the variable is assigned to another variable, the value is copied<sup>1</sup> into the new variable.

For example:

```
$x = array('a');
$y = $x;
// $x and $y are different and unrelated variables; they do not share anything
$y[] = 'b';
print_r($y);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => a
//     [1] => b
// )
print_r($x);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => a
// )
```

#### How PHP handles the objects assignment?

The objects, on the other hand, are handled by PHP using unique identifiers. When an object is assigned to a variable, the identifier is stored in the variable and not the actual object.

When the value of the variable is assigned to another variable, the identifier is copied and not the object itself. This makes the two variables point to the same object.

Using your example, the values of variables `$instance` and `$assigned` are equal, they both contain the identifier of the same object. `$reference`, on the other side, is a reference, i.e. an alias (a different name) of variable `$assigned`. This is why the statement `$instance = null;` clears the content of variables `$reference` and `$assigned` but it doesn't affect the variable `$instance` and also the object whose identifier is stored in it.

Before setting `$reference` to `null`, one can use any of `$instance`, `$assigned` or `reference` to access the `SimpleClass` object created on the first line of your example. F.e:

```
$instance = new SimpleClass();
$assigned = $instance;

$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
echo($instance->var);
// It prints: 
// $assigned will have this value

// $assigned is also modified because it is the same object
echo($assigned->var);
// It prints: 
// $assigned will have this value
```

Read more about [PHP objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in the documentation.

#### What happens when `$assigned = clone $instance`?

The [`clone` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)  creates a duplicate of its operand. It creates a new object and it initializes all its properties by assigning the values of the properties of the original object to them. This means that if the clone object contains objects as properties, these properties are duplicated by simple assignment, not by cloning.<sup>2</sup>

```
$assigned = clone $instance;
```

After this statement, `$assigned` contains a different value than `$instance` because they store now the IDs of different objects. Being different objects, the changes of `$instance` do not affect `$assigned` any more.

```
$instance = new SimpleClass();
$instance->var = '$instance has this value';

$assigned = clone $instance;
echo($assigned->var);
// It prints: 
// $instance has this value

$assigned->var = '$assigned has a different value';
echo($assigned->var);
// It prints:
// $assigned has a different value

// $instance is not modified
echo($instance->var);
// It prints: 
// $instance has this value
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not entirely true. For optimization purposes, the arrays are not copied until they are modified (copy-on-write). However, this is an implementation detail and for the purpose of this discussion it is fine to consider all values except the objects are copied when they are assigned to a new variable.

<sup>2</sup> This is also called "shallow" cloning. In order to get a "deep" clone (a real duplicate that doesn't share anything with the original), the class of a cloned object that has objects as properties must implement the [`__clone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) magic method and clone the properties of the original object. Also, the classes of these properties must implement `__clone()` and so on.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the reason why `$instance = null; echo $assigned->var;` still works is because `$instance = null;` doesn't destroy the object, but only clears the pointer to the object that was stored in `$instance` and so the object is still accessible through `$assigned`. It's not until `$assigned` is also cleared and there are no more pointers to the object that it is removed from memory.

Answer (score 1):

well, basically those variables are nothing but pointers to the memory space, where object resides. If you store pointer value in another pointer, and then reset original pointer, nothing will happen to the memory area they both once pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $assigned = $instance
```

Above will assign $instance to $assigned, the most basic assign.

```
 $assigned = clone $instance
```

This is for object clone. Assign a copy of object $instance to $assigned.

**Without clone, $assigned  and $instance  has same object id, which means they are pointing to same object.**

Comment: but the other person saying `so obviously $assigned isn't a reference but a copy of $instance `

Answer (score 1):

here is the difference  between clone and assignment:

```
class MyClass {
  public $color;
  public $amount;
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->color = 'red';
$obj->amount = 5;
$copy = clone $obj;
$assign = $obj;
$obj->amount = 7;
print_r($copy);//it will print : MyClass Object ( [color] => red [amount] => 5 ) 
print_r($assign);//it will print : MyClass Object ( [color] => red [amount] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Keeping it Short & Simple Here :**

Here `$reference` is like an alias to the object `$instance`. Whereas initially `$assignment` and `$reference` are pointing to the data space for the object `$instance`.

And when there is a change in the value that is being pointed by `$instance` it will be changed everywhere.

But when `$instance = null`, here we are making the `$instance` to point to `null` and since `$reference` is an alias so:

> $reference -> $instance -> null....

Whereas `$assignment` still holds the pointer to data space for object created by `$instance`, but now `$instance` no longer needs the same.

Answer (score -3):

It just makes a completely new object, which retains the properties of the object being copied. It performs a deep copy:

```
$assigned = $instance;
```

It makes a shallow copy when you copy an object from one to another:

```
$assigned = clone $instance;
```

Comment: `$assigned = $instance;` doesn't perform any copy. It just creates another variable that points to the same object.