# Does duplicating the PDO object create multiple connections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a question about using PDO that I haven't been able to find an answer to.  This probably works the same for mysql/mysqli connections as well.

In the main include of my project, I create a PDO object using

```
$pdo = new PDO('connection here');
```

Well, I have a class that needs access to the database.  So, instead of using "global $pdo;" inside of every function, I did the following.

```
class MyClass(){
    private $db = null;
    __construct(){
        global $pdo;
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }
    function example(){
        $sql = 'A Query';
        $this->db->prepare($sql);
    }
 }
```

Anyway, my question is, does doing this create 2 connections to the database since I'm effectively duplicating $pdo by setting the class' $db var equal to it?  The main reason I ask is because I see this happening a lot in our system and am concerned with creating too many connections to MySQL and freaking the system out due to unnecessary connections.

As a part two, does the following cause duplication, and can I pass by ref?  I'm a bit afraid to try it and cause something to break.

Change

```
function MyFunction($member_id, $pdo){
    //do something.
}
```

To

```
function MyFunction($member_id, &$pdo){
   //do something
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just answered this earlier: [PHP Object Assignment vs Cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893949/php-object-assignment-vs-cloning). The answer should clear up your confusion.

Comment: This is the same object, as objects are always stored with references

Comment: On a side note, does the connection returned from an old school mysql_connect() fall under these rules?

Comment: @GameCharmer That returns something called a "resource", which is another odd kind of variable; however, like an object, the "value" of the variable is just the ID of the resource, so assignment will work similarly to an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by deceze in comments, you are not actually duplicating the PDO object in this code, you are just assigning an extra variable to reference the same object.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894059/157957) explains in detail, but to summarise, objects have an extra level of indirection - even if you don't pass by reference, you are still only copying a *pointer* to the object, not the object itself.

Passing by reference is only necessary if you actually want to modify the variable and have the modifications propagate back; assigning a completely new object to `$pdo` inside the function would be considered modifying the variable, but manipulating the object would not.

Counter-intuitively, assigning by reference is often *worse* for performance, as it defeats "copy on write" optimisations in the PHP engine which let separate variables with the same value share the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

It will not create two connections.To confirm you can use :
xdebug_debug_zval.Check the php manual for usage.
You can check the result with the helkp of below code : 
xdebug_debug_zval('pdo'); and xdebug_debug_zval('db');