# PHP Seems To Be Assigning By Reference, Not By Value

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I am using the following code:

```
$input = new DateTime(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'date'));
$input->modify('midnight');

echo $input->format(DateTime::RFC3339) . "\n";

$end = $input;
$end->modify('+3 hours');
echo $input->format(DateTime::RFC3339) . "\n";
echo $end->format(DateTime::RFC3339) . "\n";
```

Which is giving the following output:

```
2016-02-01T00:00:00-5:00
2016-02-01T03:00:00-5:00
2016-02-01T03:00:00-5:00
```

Shouldn't the output on line two be the same as the first?

From what I understand to assign a variable by reference you need to use `$a = &$b`, so what I am using (`$a = $b`) should be by value. So an function called on `$end` should not modify `$input` as well, correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Don't confuse scalar variables with object instances..... instances are always a pointer

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) - `When assigning an already created instance of a class to a new variable, the new variable will access the same instance as the object that was assigned. This behaviour is the same when passing instances to a function. A copy of an already created object can be made by cloning it.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `DateTime` is object and objects is assigned always by reference. If you want assign by "value", you must use cloning like `$end = clone $input;`.

Here is information about it in PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: This may be worth a read too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893949/php-object-assignment-vs-cloning

Comment: Okay, did not know that, thank you. As a side note, would you happen to know why this is? It just seems counter-intuitive to me, especially considering normal variables are assigned by value, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: This is because objects is represented only by reference to memory instead of scalars which is represented by own value, like Mark Baker mentioned.