# For loops copy objects by reference, even though documentation says they copy objects by value?

Tags: php, for-loop, reference

I'm a little confused on the behavior of for loops when iterating over an array of objects.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) says

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Based on that, I was under the impression `$value` was a copy (by value) of the object in the array. However, to verify I just ran this test:

```
class test {
    public $foo = 1;
    function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

$testArray = array();
$testArray[] = new test(1);
$testArray[] = new test(2);
$testArray[] = new test(3);;

echo '$testArray' . '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($testArray);
echo PHP_EOL . '</pre>';

foreach ($testArray as $test) {
    if ($test->foo == 2) {
        $temp = $test;
    }
}

$temp->foo = 'copied by value or reference?';

echo '$testArray' . '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($testArray);
echo PHP_EOL . '</pre>';
```

Surprisingly, the output is:

```
$testArray
Array
(
    [0] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 1
        )

    [1] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 2
        )

    [2] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 3
        )

)

$testArray
Array
(
    [0] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 1
        )

    [1] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => copied by value or reference?
        )

    [2] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 3
        )

)
```

My confusion is that when I did the `$temp = $test` assignment it did a copy by reference to the original object in the array, but I thought `$test` had been copied by value according to the documentation?

---

OK, so maybe I just didn't pay attention to the fine print:

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements **within the loop** precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

So lets try a test where we modify the object inside the loop:

```
class test {
    public $foo = 1;
    function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

$testArray = array();
$testArray[] = new test(1);
$testArray[] = new test(2);
$testArray[] = new test(3);;

echo '$testArray' . '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($testArray);
echo PHP_EOL . '</pre>';

foreach ($testArray as $test) {
    if ($test->foo == 2) {
        $temp = $test;
        $temp->foo = 'copied by value or reference?';
    }
}

echo '$testArray' . '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($testArray);
echo PHP_EOL . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
$testArray
Array
(
    [0] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 1
        )

    [1] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 2
        )

    [2] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 3
        )

)

$testArray
Array
(
    [0] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 1
        )

    [1] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => copied by value or reference?
        )

    [2] => test Object
        (
            [foo] => 3
        )

)
```

The result is the same. It appears the object is copied by reference, even though the documentation clearly insinuates they are copied by value.

What gives?

Comment: Aren't objects always given by reference in php? Contrary to scalar variables... It's the case for function parameters at least, or am i mistaken?

Comment: @fpierrat Then why does the documentation say to include the reference symbol `&` before `$value` to copy by reference?

Comment: For scalar elements. Abt objects, variables and references, see http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.references.php (maybe replace fr with en...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as
>   value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows
>   object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by
>   argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different
>   variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which
>   points to the same object.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

**Edit:** For the first time I just had the reverse issue, *I needed to copy an object by value*.
As simply as `$new_obj = clone $original_obj` if your object is simple...  it soon becomes a nightmare if you have an object containing other objects, eventually in arrays or sub-arrays! Several `__clone()` magic functions in differents classes and some headaches for some tricky cases...
I finally wiped out all this `clone` and `__clone()` stuff and chose following solution:

```
$new_obj = unserialize(serialize($original_obj));
```

Here interesting pro/con-comments about this solution, which in my case was the best one - or at least the easiest one :-) :  [How do I create a copy of an object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185934/how-do-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-php)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quote and the link. So there's a lot of legacy code out there now using `&` before objects and it's not necessary any more..