# CodeIgniter deep copy of object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$this->load->model('funders_model');

        $funders = $this->funders_model->getAllLike($name);

        $opportunities = array();

        foreach($funders as $funder) {

            $query = "SELECT funding_opportunities.id FROM funding_opportunities WHERE funder = " . $funder->id;

            $exec_query = $this->db->query($query);

            $row = $exec_query->row();


            $funding_opportunity = $this->getFromId($row->id);

            if(!is_null($funding_opportunity))
                $opportunities[] = $funding_opportunity;

        }


        return $opportunities;
```

What the code does is it gets an array of 'funder' objects and, for each, retrieves a 'funding_opportunity' object.

My problem is that when I try adding the opportunity to the $opportunities array, each loop cycle overwrites the previous one.

I tried using the 'clone' call on $funding_opportunity before adding it, but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `var_dump` each `$funding_opportunity` Maybe you have only one opportunity?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/186008/1745573) may help you.

Comment: It should not overwrite. Do as @u_mulder says.