# PHP how to assign new value to object without updating previous value

Tags: php, arrays, object

This is the code for an object:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->value = 'key';
$array[] = $a;
$array[] = $a;
$a->value = 'key2';
$array[] = $a;
print_r($array);
```

and this is the code for an array

```
$a = array("value" => "key");
$array[] = $a;
$array[] = $a;
$a['value'] = 'key2';
$array[] = $a;
print_r($array);
```

output for object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => key2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => key2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => key2
        )

)
```

output for array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => key
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => key
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => key2
        )

)
```

When `$a` is an Object, it updates the value already in `$array` to `key2` but when `$a`is an array it only updates the last value. How can I get the object to behave like the array and only update the last value?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a copy of an object in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185934/how-do-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP objects are automatically [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new), so if you update the last one it will update everything. So just use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), to clone your object, e.g.

```
$array[] = clone $a;
         //^^^^^ See here
```