# unexpected changes - overriding object inside foreach php

Tags: php, sql, object, foreach

I've got array of object form database like below:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#99 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "42"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "NAME1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "6"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#98 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "146"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "STH1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#97 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "422"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "NAME2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#96 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "16"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "STH2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#95 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "NAME3"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#94 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "69"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "STH3"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
  }
}
```

And if i want to add the same object to the next array and change value of its type, i override the current object. How can i fix it? My foreach loop below:

```
foreach($events as $key => $event){
    foreach($event as $k => $v){
        if($v->type == 6){
            $v->type = "0";
            $events[$key+1][] = $v;
            $v->type = "6";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to duplicate the object form $events[1][0] to $events[2][2] with different type (example '0')

Comment: what does this question have to do with sql?

Comment: these data i get form sql

Answer (score 0):

If my guess what you are trying to achieve is right i would go like this

```
foreach($events as $key => $event){
    foreach($event as $k => $v){
        if($v->type == 6){
            $tmp = $v;
            $tmp->type="0";
            $events[$key+1][] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any changes - it override the first object too!

Comment: @jdoe So i think that your problem is somewhere else, first gues is having several objects with same id. if you are indexing column with events by id, than secound instance with same id and different type will just update old entry

Comment: i've already found solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/185939/6648280