# How to unset the id of a cloned PHP object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, clone, auto-increment

I am working on a project that uses Docrtrine and Symfony 2.7. I have a Document entity that I want to clone, and I of course need to make sure that  I don't have a duplicate primary key. Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
/**
 * Document
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents")
 */
class Document {
    public function __clone(){
        $newObj = clone $this;
        $newObj->id = null;
        return $newObj;
    }
...
}
```

This does not seem to do much, however, as when I call `clone myDocument` and then try to persist, I still get this message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '1' for key 'UNIQ_A2B07288ECC6147F'

How can I get my object's primary key to revert to a null or auto-incremented state?

=====

Upate: Using

```
public function __clone(){
    $this->id = null;
}
```

still results in the same error. Full error text:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO documents
> (usageFrom, usageTo, status, workflow_identifier, created_date,
> modified_date, language_id, translationRoot_id, ownerGroup_id,
> responsibleUser_id, production_id, media_id, created_user,
> modified_user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
> params ["2018-06-28 09:54:37", "2018-06-28 09:54:37", 100,
> "4cc723c2a5730c1b9c2ed6428ae57205", "2018-06-28 09:54:37", "2018-06-28
> 09:54:37", null, null, null, null, 1, null, 1, 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '1' for key 'UNIQ_A2B07288ECC6147F'

Comment: try with [detach](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) or make a copy constructor (or check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186008/2270041) works for you)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not how [PHP’s cloning](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.cloning.php) works. Think of `__clone` like of `__construct`. In the `__clone` method, you must assign the new values to `$this`.

```
class Document 
{
    public function ___clone()
    {
        // simple as that
        $this->id = null;
    }
}
```

In your current code, the `$newObj` is going to be thrown away, while the cloned object still has the original ID.

Also, remember to clone child objects in your `__clone` method if you want to create a deep copy, otherwise you’ll end up with two entities referencing the same children. (Or, after persisting/reloading: One of the entities will have lost its children.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question to show what happens when I try your suggestion.

Comment: Is the `UNIQ_A2B07288ECC6147F` index on the Document table or one of the child tables?

Comment: Aha -- it looks like it's not a problem with the ID. From the MAKE TABLE statement for my documents table: 

`UNIQUE KEY UNIQ_A2B07288ECC6147F (production_id),`

... so that's a nice catch.

Comment: is the `production` entity a child entity of `document` or an independent entity?

Comment: It's an entity of its own.

Comment: You didn’t detach the entity or clear the entity manager, did you? Because it looks like Doctrine is trying to persist the Production entity again.

Comment: Correct -- I didn't detach the entity, nor did I clear the entity manager.