# Object getting mysteriously overridden

Tags: php, oop

Somehow `$this->processes->data` gets expanded everytime I call `$this->load_operations()`. I do not really understand why that object changes when my code clearly does not modify it.

Am I missing something?

If I cast `$process` (in the foreach) to array and then back to object `$this->processes->data` does not get expanded.

```
$process = (array) $process;
$process = (object) $process;
```

```php
class Test_library
{
    private $processes;
    private $tasks;
    private $operations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->processes = (object) array(
            'data' => (object) array(
                '3' => (object) array(
                    'id' => '3',
                )
            )
        );

        $this->tasks = (object) array(
            'data' => (object) array(
                '5' => (object) array(
                    'id' => '5',
                    'processes_id' => '3',
                ),
                '6' => (object) array(
                    'id' => '6',
                    'processes_id' => '3',
                )
            )
        );

        $this->operations = (object) array(
            'processes' => (object) array(
                '3' => (object) array(
                    'id' => '3',
                    'data' => array()
                )
            )
        );

        print_r($this->processes->data);

        $this->load_operations();

        print_r($this->processes->data);
    }

    private function load_operations()
    {
        if(!empty($this->processes->data))
        {
            foreach($this->processes->data as $process)
            {
                $this->operations->processes->{$process->id} = $process;
            }
        }

        if(!empty($this->tasks->data))
        {
            foreach($this->tasks->data as $task)
            {
                $this->operations->processes->{$task->processes_id}->data[] = (object) [
                    'machine' => [],
                    'task' => $task
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}

new Test_Library;
```

The result of the two `print_r` should be the same.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: @Progman this seems to me to be an excellent example of a [mcve]. Only thing missing is instantiation of the object, which I've added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that objects are, roughly speaking, passed by reference. The details can be found [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

In your first `foreach` loop, you are assigning a reference to `$this->processes->data->3` to `$this->operations->processes->3`

```
        foreach($this->processes->data as $process) {
            $this->operations->processes->{$process->id} = $process;
        }
```

In the next loop, you are appending to the `data` property of `$this->operations->processes->3` which you just established as a reference to  `$this->processes->data->3`.

```
        foreach($this->tasks->data as $task) {
            $this->operations->processes->{$task->processes_id}->data[] = (object) [
                'machine' => [],
                'task' => $task
            ];
        }
```

To get around this behaviour, you might try using the `clone` operator during assignment in the first loop ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185934/how-do-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-php) for more details) or simply use associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Adding `$process_clone = clone $process;` to the first foreach have solved my issue.